# error during calculation multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, floor

i found a error

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

in my c# project. i want to convert my decimal value to round but if value is "7.99" it's output is 7 only which is at "b". i use this function but i failed.

```
void Calculation()
   {
        double a = Convert.ToDouble(lblTFPc.Text); **//Error appears here**
        double b = Convert.ToDouble(lbl1.Text);
        double c = Convert.ToDouble(lblTPc.Text);
        double d = Convert.ToDouble(lblSchOn.Text);
        try
        {

            a = (c / d);

            b = Math.Floor(a +0.0);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Error" + ex, "Stop", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

i changed the way but still an error

```
void Calculation()
    {
        try
        {
            decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal(txtValue.Text);
            decimal b = Convert.ToDecimal(lblCtn.Text);
            decimal c = Convert.ToDecimal(lblPc.Text);

            decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(lblCtnInPc.Text);
            decimal e = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQtyCtn.Text);
            decimal f = Convert.ToDecimal(lblCtnSize.Text);

            decimal g = Convert.ToDecimal(lblTotalPc.Text);
            decimal h = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQtyPc.Text);

            decimal i = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalFreePc.Text); **//error is here I change lbl into txtbox but error still**
            decimal j = Convert.ToDecimal(lblSchemeOn.Text);

            decimal k = Convert.ToDecimal(lbl1.Text);

            a = (b + c);
            d = (e * f);
            g = (h + d);
            i = (g / j);
            k = Math.Floor(i);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Error" + ex, "Stop", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

with try error is like this:

> ErrorSystem.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String Str, NumberStryles options, NumberBuffer number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NUmberFormatInfo numfmt)
>   atSystem.Convert.ToDecimal(String value)
>   at MyProject.Forms.frmPurchaseItem.Calculation() in [Filepath]

Comment: Well, what are the values of a,b,c,d?

Comment: The error tells you everything you need to know. The value of `lblTFPc.Text` must not be in a proper format. Set a breakpoint on that line and inspect the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lbl is Control abbreviation for label and for textbox is txt. Check if the labels in your text property have text and not number. Maybe you put the label instead of the text boxes. Convert.ToDouble() can not perform the conversion if there is text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using in textbox "0,55" value instead of "0.55". Or you can use TryParse function too.

```
double result=0;
if(Double.TryParse(lblTFPc.Text, out result))
...
```

Comment: I would use this format instead of Convert.  This way you can meaningfully handle when the input is not numeric and cannot be parsed as a double, rather than getting an exception.